# Docker wait for postgresql to be running

Tags: postgresql, docker

I am using postgresql with django in my project. I've got them in different containers and the problem is that i need to wait for postgres before running django. At this time i am doing it with `sleep 5` in `command.sh` file for django container. I also found that netcat can do the trick but I would prefer way without additional packages. `curl` and `wget` can't do this because they do not support postgres protocol.
Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Since you have Python in that container, you could write a small script that does the same as `nc -z postgres:5432` or tries to connect to postgres via psycopg.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Problem with your solution tiziano is that curl is not installed by default and i wanted to avoid installing additional stuff. Anyway i did what bereal said. Here is the script if anyone would need it.

```
import socket
import time
import os

port = int(os.environ["DB_PORT"]) # 5432

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
while True:
    try:
        s.connect(('myproject-db', port))
        s.close()
        break
    except socket.error as ex:
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: The problem with your solution is that python is not installed by default and I wanted to avoid installing additional stuff. ;)

Comment: :-D though to be fair the OP is using Django and thus will have python installed

Answer (score 216):

I've spent some hours investigating this problem and I got a solution.
Docker `depends_on` just consider service startup to run another service. Than it happens because as soon as `db` is started, service-app tries to connect to ur `db`, but it's not ready to receive connections. So you can check `db` health status in app service to wait for connection. Here is my solution, it solved my problem. :)
Important: I'm using docker-compose version 2.1.

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  my-app:
    build: .
    command: su -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    ports:
       - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - .:/app_directory

  db:
    image: postgres:10.5
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

volumes:
  database:
```

In this case it's not necessary to create a .sh file.

Comment: `depends_on` does not accept the form `condition` as of compose 3.x

Comment: I may be wrong, but I'm using 3.8 and it is working for me. I even took it out as a test and it broke again.

Comment: nice, thanks for the `pg_isready` tip. neat command.

Comment: The `condition` property is no longer documented for `depends_on` in the [compose file v3 reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#depends_on), but it is documented in the [compose file v2 reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#depends_on), and it seems to be supported on both (I'm using it in 3.5). I've gone through their issue tracker and they talk about it breaking docker swarm, so they say they only support the short form (with no `condition`) but it doesn't seem to be true yet.

Comment: Great! This is the first answer I've seen that doesn't require an additional script

Comment: Is there a way to do something similar on a file with v3?

Comment: Just to clear up the confusion in the comments, it works now because v2 and v3 have both been superseded by [a new specification](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)

Comment: It is now documented, this solution works for 3.8 -> https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on

Comment: if you are not docker-compose v1.27 or newer, just remove the `version` from file, and use the `condition`.

Comment: To clear things up in 2023, **docker deprecated the `version: X` syntax in compose YAML files**. The extremely confusing part is that Docker announced this by "*Announcing Compose V2*" (meaning version 2 of Docker Compose itself, not V2 of the YML version). I think that was a major blunder on their end because the majority of people will think they mean YML version 2... but versions are no longer a "thing". See: https://www.docker.com/blog/tag/compose-v2/

Comment: this worked for me with compose 3.8 and postgresql

Answer (score 75):

This will successfully wait for Postgres to start. (Specifically line 6). Just replace `npm start` with whatever command you'd like to happen after Postgres has started.

```
services:
  practice_docker: 
    image: dockerhubusername/practice_docker
    ports: 
      - 80:3000
    command: bash -c 'while !</dev/tcp/db/5432; do sleep 1; done; npm start'
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:password@db:5432/practicedocker
      - PORT=3000   
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=practicedocker
```

Comment: This works for me. Adding the lines below in  docker-compose.yml resolved the issue & allows me to test my dockerized Django web app with Postgres in Travis. `command: bash -c 'while !</dev/tcp/db/5432; do sleep 1; done; python3 manage.py migrate'` `command: bash -c 'while !</dev/tcp/db/5432; do sleep 1; done; python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000'`

Comment: For some reason if database could not able to start then in that case it will wait infinitely..right?

Comment: @ShubhamKhandare you could use `restart: always` on db

Comment: Would this work essentially the same if I rely on a Dockerfile for my entrypoint? i.e., add this to the CMD instruction in the Dockerfile?

Comment: If you need to quote your startup command, then you need to 1. replace single with double quotes and 2. escape the inner double quotes. E.g. `bash -c "while !</dev/tcp/db/5432; do sleep 1; done; gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5001  \"app:create_app()\""`

Comment: I'm trying to wait for localstack and have this as the command, can someone confirm if this is correct? command: sh -c 'while ! nc -z localhost 4566; do sleep 1; done; npm run test:int'

Comment: What if my container does not have `bash`? `sh` is available though

Comment: Can you include an explanation of what this is doing?

Comment: It is doing '<'

Answer (score 48):

If you have `psql` you could simply add the following code to your .sh file:

```
RETRIES=5

until psql -h $PG_HOST -U $PG_USER -d $PG_DATABASE -c "select 1" > /dev/null 2>&1 || [ $RETRIES -eq 0 ]; do
  echo "Waiting for postgres server, $((RETRIES--)) remaining attempts..."
  sleep 1
done
```

Comment: It worked with slight modification, added **RETRIES=$((RETRIES-=1))**. Here is the modified version:        
 `until psql -h $HOST -U $USER -d $DATABASE -c "select 1" > /dev/null 2>&1 || [ $RETRIES -eq 0 ]; do
  echo "Waiting for postgres server to start, $((RETRIES)) remaining attempts..."
  RETRIES=$((RETRIES-=1))
  sleep 1
done`

Comment: This solution assumes you install the Postgres client utilities into the web container which bloats the image and adds to the attack vector

Comment: If you don't have Postgres utilities in your container [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52795933/5911206) answer should help. It helped me.

Answer (score 32):

The simplest solution is a short bash script:

```
while ! nc -z HOST PORT; do sleep 1; done;
./run-smth-else;
```

Comment: Your container needs to have netcat installed.

Answer (score 17):

In your `Dockerfile` add [wait](https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait) and change your start command to use it:

```
ADD https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait/releases/download/2.7.3/wait /wait
RUN chmod +x /wait

CMD /wait && npm start
```

Then, in your `docker-compose.yml` add a `WAIT_HOSTS` environment variable for your api service:

```yaml
services:
  api: 
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - WAIT_HOSTS: postgres:5432

  postgres:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

This has the advantage that it supports waiting for multiple services:

```yaml
environment:
  - WAIT_HOSTS: postgres:5432, mysql:3306, mongo:27017
```

For more details, please read [their documentation](https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait#docker-compose-wait).

Answer (score 15):

[wait-for-it](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) small wrapper scripts which you can include in your application’s image to poll a given host and port until it’s accepting TCP connections.

can be cloned in Dockerfile by below command

```
RUN git clone https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it.git
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
   web:
     build: .
     ports:
       - "80:8000"
     depends_on:
       - "db"
     command: ["./wait-for-it/wait-for-it.sh", "db:5432", "--", "npm",  "start"]
   db:
     image: postgres
```

Answer (score 14):

I have managed to solve my issue by adding health check to docker-compose definition.

```
  db:
    image: postgres:latest
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    healthcheck:
      test: "pg_isready --username=postgres && psql --username=postgres --list"
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 20
```

then in the dependent service you can check the health status:

```
  my-service:
    image: myApp:latest
    depends_on:
      kafka:
        condition: service_started
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
```

source: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#healthcheck

Comment: Note that while this was not possible for a while with "v3" compose files, it's now back.

Answer (score 12):

Why not curl?

Something like this:

```
while ! curl http://$POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR:$POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT/ 2>&1 | grep '52'
do
  sleep 1
done
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 10):

If the backend application itself has a PostgreSQL client, you can use the [`pg_isready`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/app-pg-isready.html) command in an `until` loop. For example, suppose we have the following project directory structure,

```
.
├── backend
│   └── Dockerfile
└── docker-compose.yml
```

with a `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
  backend:
    build: ./backend
```

and a `backend/Dockerfile`

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk update && apk add postgresql-client
CMD until pg_isready --username=postgres --host=postgres; do sleep 1; done \
    && psql --username=postgres --host=postgres --list
```

where the 'actual' command is just a `psql --list` for illustration. Then running `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up` will give you the following output:

[image]

Note how the result of the `psql --list` command only appears after `pg_isready` logs `postgres:5432 - accepting connections` as desired.

By contrast, I have found that the `nc -z` approach does not work consistently. For example, if I replace the `backend/Dockerfile` with

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk update && apk add postgresql-client
CMD until nc -z postgres 5432; do echo "Waiting for Postgres..." && sleep 1; done \
    && psql --username=postgres --host=postgres --list
```

then `docker-compose build` followed by `docker-compose up` gives me the following result:

[image]

That is, the `psql` command throws a `FATAL` error that `the database system is starting up`.

In short, using an `until pg_isready` loop (as also recommended [here](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/146#issuecomment-261778052)) is the preferable approach IMO.

Comment: yep, for me port checking sucks in case of  `database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress` in instance logs. This process can take a time, but server starting listening on port immediately

Answer (score 9):

There are couple of solutions as other answers mentioned.

But don't make it complicated, just let it fail-fast combined with `restart: on-failure`. Your service will open connection to the db and may fail at the first time. Just let it fail. Docker will restart your service until it green. Keep your service simple and business-focused.

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:

  postgresdb:
    hostname: postgresdb
    image: postgres:12.2
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret
      - POSTGRES_DB=Ceo

  migrate:
    image: hanh/migration
    links:
      - postgresdb
    environment:
      - DATA_SOURCE=postgres://user:secret@postgresdb:5432/Ceo
    command: migrate sql --yes
    restart: on-failure # will restart until it's success
```

Check out [restart policies](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies---restart).

Comment: If the migrations are invalid then it will keep restarting over and over?

Comment: @sdgfsdh, no really. If you specify a `max-retries` (`on-failure[:max-retries]`), it will limit the number of restart retries the Docker daemon attempts.

Answer (score 9):

None of other solution worked, except for the following:

```yaml
version : '3.8'
services :
  postgres :
    image : postgres:latest
    environment :
      - POSTGRES_DB=mydbname
      - POSTGRES_USER=myusername
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword
    healthcheck :
      test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-q", "-d", "mydbname", "-U", "myusername" ]
      interval : 5s
      timeout : 5s
      retries : 5
  otherservice:
    image: otherserviceimage
    depends_on :
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
```

Thanks to this thread: https://github.com/peter-evans/docker-compose-healthcheck/issues/16

Answer (score 5):

Sleeping until `pg_isready` returns true unfortunately is not always reliable. If your postgres container has at least one initdb script specified, [postgres restarts after it is started during it's bootstrap procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65417566/1860149), and so it might not be ready yet even though `pg_isready` already returned true.

What you can do instead, is to wait until docker logs for that instance return a `PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.` string, and only then proceed with the `pg_isready` check.

Example:

```sh
start_postgres() {
  docker-compose up -d --no-recreate postgres
}

wait_for_postgres() {
  until docker-compose logs | grep -q "PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up." \
    && docker-compose exec -T postgres sh -c "PGPASSWORD=\$POSTGRES_PASSWORD PGUSER=\$POSTGRES_USER pg_isready --dbname=\$POSTGRES_DB" > /dev/null 2>&1; do
    printf "\rWaiting for postgres container to be available ... "
    sleep 1
  done
  printf "\rWaiting for postgres container to be available ... done\n"
}

start_postgres
wait_for_postgres
```

Comment: By putting sleep to initdb scripts I concluded that at least today pg_isready is reliable and the DB isn't ready until the initdb scripts have all been run so pg_isready works as expected. This is using the connection string as the dbname parameter.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the manage.py command "check" to check if the database is available (and wait 2 seconds if not, and check again).
For instance, if you do this in your `command.sh` file before running the migration, Django has a valid DB connection while running the migration command:

```sh
...
echo "Waiting for db.."
python manage.py check --database default > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
until [ $? -eq 0 ];
do
  sleep 2
  python manage.py check --database default > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
done
echo "Connected."
# Migrate the last database changes
python manage.py migrate
...
```

PS: I'm **not** a shell expert, please suggest improvements.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

POSTGRES_VERSION=9.6.11
CONTAINER_NAME=my-postgres-container

# start the postgres container
docker run --rm \
  --name $CONTAINER_NAME \
  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=docker \
  -d \
  -p 5432:5432 \
  postgres:$POSTGRES_VERSION

# wait until postgres is ready to accept connections
until docker run \
  --rm \
  --link $CONTAINER_NAME:pg \
  postgres:$POSTGRES_VERSION pg_isready \
    -U postgres \
    -h pg; do sleep 1; done
```

Answer (score 1):

An example for Nodejs and Postgres api.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#entrypoint.dev.sh
echo "Waiting for postgres to get up and running..."
while ! nc -z postgres_container 5432; do
  # where the postgres_container is the hos, in my case, it is a Docker container.
  # You can use localhost for example in case your database is running locally.
  echo "waiting for postgress listening..."
  sleep 0.1
done
echo "PostgreSQL started"

yarn db:migrate

yarn dev
```

```
# Dockerfile
FROM node:12.16.2-alpine

ENV NODE_ENV="development"

RUN mkdir -p /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./package.json ./yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

CMD ["/bin/sh", "./entrypoint.dev.sh"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run it with a single line command. You can just connect to the container and check if postgres is running

```
docker exec -it $DB_NAME bash -c "\
until psql -h $HOST -U $USER -d $DB_NAME-c 'select 1'>/dev/null 2>&1;\
do\
  echo 'Waiting for postgres server....';\
  sleep 1;\
done;\
exit;\
"
echo "DB Connected !!"
```

Answer (score 1):

According to https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/, the latest compose specification is available at: https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md and the part about the `depends_on` key is under:
https://github.com/compose-spec/compose-spec/blob/master/spec.md#depends_on

It tells us everything we need about the `condition`:

> ## `depends_on`
>
> ### Short syntax
>
> (...)
>
> ### Long syntax
>
> The long form syntax enables the configuration of additional fields
> that can't be expressed in the short form.
>
> - `restart`: When set to true Compose restarts this service after it updates the dependency service. This applies to an explicit restart
>   controlled by a Compose operation, and excludes automated restart by
>   the container runtime after the container dies.
> - `condition`: Sets the condition under which dependency is considered satisfied
>
>   - `service_started`: An equivalent of the short syntax described above
>   - `service_healthy`: Specifies that a dependency is expected to be "healthy" (as indicated by healthcheck) before starting a dependent
>     service.
>   - `service_completed_successfully`: Specifies that a dependency is expected to run to successful completion before starting a dependent
>     service.
>   - `required`: When set to false Compose only warns you when the dependency service isn't started or available. If it's not defined the
>     default value of required is true.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @tiziano [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35840329/) and the lack of `nc` or `pg_isready`, it seems that in a recent docker python image (python:3.9 here) that curl is installed by default and I have the following check running in my `entrypoint.sh`:

```
postgres_ready() {
    $(which curl) http://$DBHOST:$DBPORT/ 2>&1 | grep '52'
}

until postgres_ready; do
  >&2 echo 'Waiting for PostgreSQL to become available...'
  sleep 1
done
>&2 echo 'PostgreSQL is available.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying with a lot of methods, Dockerfile, docker compose yaml, bash script. Only last of method help me: with `makefile`.

```
docker-compose up --build -d postgres
sleep 2
docker-compose up --build -d app
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying await until a Postgres database within a container is ready, using java only. This is how I did it:

I'm representing a container that has a Postgres database using the following record:

```java
public record DBContainer(String containerId, String driverClassName, String url, String username, String password) {}
```

Then, this method awaits for the container to be ready:

```java
private static void waitForPostgresContainerToBeReady(DBContainer dbContainer) throws InterruptedException {
    while (!containerIsReady(dbContainer)) {
        System.err.println(String.format("Container %s is not ready", dbContainer.containerId()));
        Thread.sleep(Duration.ofMillis(300));
    }
    System.out.println(String.format("Container %s is ready", dbContainer.containerId()));
}
```

Additional helper methods:

```java
// Check if the postgres database whithin the container is ready by trying to open a connection to it.
private static boolean containerIsReady(DBContainer dbContainer) {
    try {
        DataSource dataSource = getDataSource(dbContainer);
        Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        boolean isOpen = !connection.isClosed();
        if (isOpen) {
            connection.close();
        }
        return isOpen;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

// Get a datasource from a DBContainer
public static DataSource getDataSource(DBContainer container) {
    DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create()
            .driverClassName(container.driverClassName())
            .url(container.url())
            .username(container.username())
            .password(container.password())
            .build();
    return dataSource;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**@Vinicius Chan** [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55835081/4632019) misses one important thing. `initdb` process [temporary runs server](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/8a631b939a0b4197cb6bef49b50b6c40c80ddf5b/15/bookworm/docker-entrypoint.sh#L265) which listens on socket. Because of this [`Sleeping until` **`pg_isready`** `returns true unfortunately is not always reliable`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67363257/4632019). Read more on [Initialization scripts](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/blob/master/postgres/README.md#initialization-scripts).

> the temporary daemon started for these initialization scripts listens only on the Unix socket

You could use this fact that temporary server is not available via TCP/IP and we could wait until that:

```
pg_isready -h localhost
```

You can use your target IP instead of `localhost` if you used `listen_addresses` option to start your server.

Related: https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/474#issuecomment-416914741

Answer (score 0):

For Java devs.
I've packed DatabaseStartupValidator into DataSource wrapper. Works like a charm:

```
public class WaitingDataSource implements DataSource, InitializingBean {

private final DataSource dataSource;
private final DatabaseStartupValidator databaseStartupValidator;

public WaitingDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = Objects.requireNonNull(dataSource);
    this.databaseStartupValidator = new DatabaseStartupValidator();
    databaseStartupValidator.setDataSource(dataSource);
}

public WaitingDataSource(DataSource dataSource, int intervalSeconds, int timeoutSeconds) {
    this(dataSource);
    databaseStartupValidator.setInterval(intervalSeconds);
    databaseStartupValidator.setTimeout(timeoutSeconds);
}

@Override
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return dataSource.getConnection();
}

@Override
public Connection getConnection(String username, String password) throws SQLException {
    return dataSource.getConnection(username, password);
}

@Override
public PrintWriter getLogWriter() throws SQLException {
    return dataSource.getLogWriter();
}

@Override
public void setLogWriter(PrintWriter printWriter) throws SQLException {
    dataSource.setLogWriter(printWriter);
}

@Override
public void setLoginTimeout(int seconds) throws SQLException {
    dataSource.setLoginTimeout(seconds);
}

@Override
public int getLoginTimeout() throws SQLException {
    return dataSource.getLoginTimeout();
}

@Override
public Logger getParentLogger() throws SQLFeatureNotSupportedException {
    return dataSource.getParentLogger();
}

@Override
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> clazz) throws SQLException {
    return clazz.isInstance(this) ? (T) this : dataSource.unwrap(clazz);
}

@Override
public boolean isWrapperFor(Class<?> clazz) throws SQLException {
    return clazz.isInstance(this) || dataSource.isWrapperFor(clazz);
}

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() {
    this.databaseStartupValidator.afterPropertiesSet();
}
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).