# Starting postgres service in docker entry script

Tags: django, postgresql, docker

I am new to docker and I want to put my django website inside a docker container. I have setup the container as described here: 
http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2015/04/19/packaging-django-applications-as-docker-container-images/

I also created an entry script named `entryPointScript.sh` that contains the following:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    service postgresql start
    sleep 2s #sleep for two seconds
    source /srv/project/EnvProject/bin/activate
    python /srv/project/manage.py collectstatic --noinput  # Collect static files
    python /srv/project/manage.py migrate_schemas                  # Apply database migrations

    # Prepare log files and start outputting logs to stdout
    touch /srv/logs/gunicorn.log
    touch /srv/logs/access.log
    tail -n 0 -f /srv/logs/*.log &

    # Start Gunicorn processes
    #echo Starting Gunicorn.
    # exec gunicorn project.wsgi:application \
    #     --name project \
    #     --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 \
    #     --workers 3 \
    #     --log-level=info \
    #     --log-file=/srv/logs/gunicorn.log \
    #     --access-logfile=/srv/logs/access.log \
    #     "$@"

    #Export Python Path
    PYTHONPATH=/srv/project/Envproject/bin

    # Start Uwsgi Process
    echo Starting Uwsgi
    exec uwsgi
         --http :8000
         --socket 0.0.0.0:8000
         --home /srv/project/Envproject/
         --chdir /srv/project/project
         --wsgi-file /srv/project/project/wsgi.py
         --uid root
         --pythonpath /srv/project/Envproject/
```

However, when I start the container using the following command:

```
docker run -i -t --entrypoint=/entryPointScript.sh nikssardana/project
```

Django throws an error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  the database system is starting up
```

I think the postgresql service is taking too long to start. How can I avoid the error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35069027/1005215

Comment: @NehalJWani I saw the answer mentioned there and wrote a script that does something similar to the python script in that answer. Whenever I try to connect to the server, it says: "FATAL:  the database system is starting up"

Comment: I guess the problem is solved. After waiting for one minute or so, it connects to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote the following script to check whether the postgresql server is running or not

```
    #Check if postgres is running or not
    import psycopg2
    import time

    while True:
        try:
            conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='wottaspace' user='root' host='localhost' password='root'")
            print 'connected'
            break
        except Exception as ex:
            print ex
            time.sleep(0.5)
```

And included this script instead of the `sleep 2s` statement. Problem solved!

Comment: Even when started it's still throwing this error, but it's only on windows, on linux everything is great!