# Sequelize docker connection refused

Tags: node.js, docker-compose, sequelize.js, koa

I'm building an app running on NodeJS using postgresql. I'm using SequelizeJS as ORM. I have been trying to dockerize my app but get this error message:

```
 SequelizeConnectionRefusedError: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.21.0.2:5432
```

My docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: sAjs21312ls
      POSTGRES_DB: dev-player
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  app:
    build: .
    environment:
      DB_USER: postgres
      DB_PASSWORD: sAjs21312ls
      DB_NAME: dev-player
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8090:8090"
```

My sequelize connection:

```
const connection = new sequelize(
    'dev-player',
    'postgres',
    'sAjs21312ls',
    {
        host: 'db',
        port: 5432,
        dialect: 'postgres'
    }
);
```

Comment: Is this the first time you're starting the postgres server? Remember that the database does not start in an instant - it may take some time before it starts listening to connections. Does this same issue occur if you wait for the database to be up (so that you can connect to it manually via `psql`)?

Comment: If the issue _is_ that the database simply hasn't had time to initialize yet when the backend already starts attempting to connect, I suspect that you may find helpful answers in this question: [_"Docker wait for postgresql to be running_"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35069027/996081)