# Docker-compose not running mysql service but only spring-boot service with UnknownHostException on database connection why?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker-compose, spring-data-jpa

am trying to deploy a web service built on spring-boot on docker using docker-compose and getting `UnknownHostException` when spring is starting as spring-boot will test connection on startup. The application persists data on mysql server, using spring-jpa to access persistence layer. When I try to use `docker-compose up` and from the logs I see logs only about building application service not the mysql server, am new to docker and you will find below the `Dockerfile`, `docker-compose.yml`and relevant configuration files.

I have spent dozens of hours trying to figure out what is wrong, I search the internet with many mentioning that maybe spring-boot service isn't waiting for mysql container to start, so I used other options including `wait-for-it` script.

Here is my docker-compose file.

```
version: '3.3'

services:

  app_database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - mysql_db_data_container:/var/lib/mysql
    expose:
      - 3306
    networks:
      - cyb-networks
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: '*database_name*'
      MYSQL_USER: 'root'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '*password*'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: '*password*'


  app_service:

    restart: on-failure
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

    depends_on:
      - app_database

    links:
      - app_database
    networks:
      - cyb-networks

networks:
  cyb-networks:

volumes:
  mysql_db_data_container:
```

the Dockerfile file

```
FROM maven:3.5.2-jdk-8-alpine
COPY pom.xml /tmp/
COPY tomcat-users.xml /tmp/
COPY src /tmp/src/
WORKDIR /tmp/
RUN mvn package

FROM tomcat:9.0-jre8-alpine
COPY /tmp/target/AppService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/AppService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war

COPY /tmp/tomcat-users.xml /usr/local/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml
CMD ["./wait-for-it.sh", "app_database:","catalina.sh", "run"]
```

And the wait-for-it.sh file

```
#!/bin/sh
# wait-for-postgres.sh

set -e

host="$1"
shift
cmd="$@"

until PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD psql -h "$host" -U "postgres" -c '\q'; do
  >&2 echo "Postgres is unavailable - sleeping"
  sleep 1
done

>&2 echo "Postgres is up - executing command"
exec $cmd
```

Although the variable names in the above script have postgres names, I assumed these are just variable names and won't affect its purpose [docker doc](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/). There are so many problems with these setup that I don't seem to wrap my head around, such as not being able to use the tomcat-admin ui, and every time I run `docker-compose up` the dependencies are downloaded again.

This an excerpt from the spring application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://app_database:3306/*database_name*?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = *password*
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Can anyone help me resolve this please? Thanks.

Comment: spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://app_database:3306/*database_name*?useSSL=false, sorry the datasource url is supposed to be as stated here, but this configuration does not work.

Comment: i think, you have the same probleme like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35069027/docker-wait-for-postgresql-to-be-running, you have to make a health check on the status of the db before starting the dependend service

Comment: @Devilluminati though above problem is same as mine, I do not want to downgrade on the docker-compose version, the oncondition is no longer supported.