# dial error (dial tcp 172.18.0.2:8001: connect: connection refused) when trying to run go program in one container that connects to postgres in another

Tags: postgresql, docker, go, tcp, docker-compose

I currently have two docker containers set up on my PC where one is a PostgreSQL container created with docker compose and the other contains go code to initialize a table within the PostgreSQL db. Docker compose works perfectly in creating the container/db (i am to log into it through psql outside of the container) and the go code itself runs properly outside of a container (creates tables). The problem arises when I try to run the code from inside its own container whether I try to connect to a local database or the containerized one. Both cases lead to the dial error in the title.

I'm just a beginner when it comes to docker so I know its most likely a problem on my end but here are the contents of my dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:alpine AS builder 

#adding needed env variables 
ENV GO111MODULE=on \
    CGO_ENABLED=0 \
    GOOS=linux \
    GOARCH=amd64 
    
#move to /build 
WORKDIR /build 

#copy dependancies 
COPY go.mod . 
COPY go.sum . 
RUN go mod download 

#add code to container 
COPY . .

#build app 
RUN go build -o main . 

# Move to /dist directory as the place for resulting binary folder
WORKDIR /dist

# Copy binary from build to main folder
RUN cp /build/main .

# Build a small image
FROM scratch

COPY --from=builder /dist/main /

ENV DATABASE_URL=postgres://short:password@test:8001/shorturl
    #change database url variable to match your needs 
    
# Command to run
ENTRYPOINT ["/main"]
```

and the contents of the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  database:
    container_name: test
    image: "postgres" # use latest official postgres version
    env_file:
      - ./db/database.env # configure postgres
    volumes:
      - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/ # persist data even if container shuts down
    ports:
        - "8001:5432" 
  backend: 
    build: . 
volumes:
  database-data:
```

The code itself exists in the following directory structure:

```
/project/
    ./db/ 
         db.go 
         database.env
    main.go 
    go.mod 
    go.sum 
    Dockerfile 
    docker-compose.yml
```

db.go contains:

```
package db
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/jackc/pgx/v4/pgxpool"
)

//InitDb creates a connection to our postgres db and populates it
func InitDb(dbURL string) *pgxpool.Pool {
    connPool, err := pgxpool.Connect(context.Background(), dbURL)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Unable to connect to database: %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    return connPool
}

//PopulateDb populates our databse with the appropiate tables i.e id, url, base64 encoding, visited, visit count
func PopulateDb(db *pgxpool.Pool) {
    _, err := db.Exec(context.Background(), "create table if not exists shortener (id serial primary key not null, url varchar not null, visited boolean default false, count integer default 0);")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Unable to create users table: %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Successfully created users table\n")
}
```

database.env which is used to generate the database with docker-compose contains:

```
POSTGRES_USER=short
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
POSTGRES_DB=shorturl
```

main.go contains:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "project/db"
)

func main() {
    /*
        set databse url in this format from root directory
        DATABASE_URL=postgres://user:password@host:port/database
    */
    dbURL := os.Getenv("DATABASE_URL")
    conn := db.InitDb(dbURL)
    db.PopulateDb(conn)
    defer conn.Close()
}
```

As I mentioned before running all of this outside of any containers works and populates the database and docker-compose successfully creates an instance of postgres that I can connect to locally.

What I cant do is connect to the containerized postgres through my code (ran locally or in a container) or connect to a local database from the containerized version of my code. All of those result in some variation of this error:

```
Unable to connect to database: failed to connect to `host=container_name user=short database=shorturl`: dial error (dial tcp 172.18.0.2:8001: connect: connection refused)
```

I'm curious about what I might be doing wrong in my code and/or with docker and hoping someone can run it on their end and reproduce my issues/find whats wrong.

Comment: Try change port of config with 5432. `DATABASE_URL=postgres://short:password@test:5432/shorturl`. Using `8001` is only access from outside docker-compose. Intercommunication container inside docker-compose services should work by their default port.

Answer (score 3):

I'll try to clarify what Michée Lengronne wrote, I think his answer is only partly right.

You have two containers - `test`, which has postgres running inside, and an unnamed one with your go app inside, the name for this one is determined randomly every time the container starts.

Both those containers are on the same network. That is important.

When you define `ports` with value `8001:5432`, it means that if you connect from *outside* the defined network, and you choose port `8001` to connect, it will connect to port `5432` on the inside.

But if you connect only from *within* the same network, you may omit the `ports` definition and go ahead and connect directly to `test` container.

> (seriously, choose a better name, `test_database` at least)

Meaning, using the container name with default port (`5432`) should be enough.

**TL;DR**

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://short:password@test:5432/shorturl
```

should work

Comment: better expained than what I wrote indeed.

Comment: thank you so much, this ended up working but i had to run docker-compose up twice since the app tried connecting to database before it was fully initialized at first.

Comment: @exef there is a solution for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35069027/docker-wait-for-postgresql-to-be-running

Comment: this helped me alot - been pulling my hair out with internal docker connectivity - ommiting the port in the endpoint on the proxy worked

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect to a local postgres or a postgres in another docker network, you must provide the IP or domain name of your postgres in that variable: `DATABASE_URL=postgres://short:password@test:8001/shorturl`

Normally you should replace `test` by `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`

From the error, your app tries to connect to `172.18.0.2`. This IP is the one from the postgres container I suppose. It is not reachable outside the docker network of this specific container. If you want to reach your container by this IP you must add your app container to the postgres docker network.

Docker network and compose: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/