# Dockerized postgres - wait in nodejs for postgres to start

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker

I am launching docker from a nodejs test environment and then running integration tests. I have to use something like:

```js
setTimeout(test, 3000);
```

Otherwise postgres may not be running yet.

Is there a way in node to wait on postgres starting on port 5432?  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35069027/docker-wait-for-postgresql-to-be-running) looks promising, but it uses `while` in `bash` and I'd need my solution to work in node to be cross-platform. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could simply try pining the 5432 port if it is used then you can move ahead.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [is-port-reachable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/is-port-reachable) for similar tasks.

All you need to do to check if the port is open, is simply

```js
await isPortReachable(5432, {host: 'PG_HOST'});
```

If you're binding PG to 5432 on the host, then replace `PG_HOST` with `localhost`, otherwise replace it with the hostname of the container which, say, docker-compose spawns; for example `mytestproj_postgresql_1`.

Another option which I have not used but looks promising is [tcp-port-used](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tcp-port-used).