# dockerized NodeJS application server throws error on unitialized database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker

I have 3 components to my app:

```
├── api (backend)
├── app (frontend)
├── db (database for api)
```

These are all defined in `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    container_name: app
    env_file: ./.env
    build:
      context: ./app
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    ports:
      - '${APP_PORT}:${APP_PORT}'
    environment:
      - API_PORT=${API_PORT}
      - API_HOST=api
      - PORT=${APP_PORT}
    init: true
    depends_on:
      - api
  api:
    container_name: api
    env_file: ./.env
    build:
      context: ./api
    volumes:
      - ./api:/api
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_PORT=${POSTGRES_PORT}
      - POSTGRES_HOST=db
      - PORT=${API_PORT}
      - APP_HOST=app
      - APP_PORT=${APP_PORT}
    ports:
      - '${API_PORT}:${API_PORT}'
      - '9229:9229'
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    container_name: db
    env_file: ./.env
    image: 'postgres:12'
    volumes: 
      - ./postgresql.conf:/etc/postgresql.conf
      - ./pg-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      - POSTGRES_PORT=${POSTGRES_PORT}
    ports:
      - '${POSTGRES_PORT}:${POSTGRES_PORT}'
```

I'm having issues with `api` container when running `docker-compose up`. This is a NodeJS Express server. This Express server connects to `db` container which is a postgres database.

When the whole container (which uses 3 images) is started up for the first time and database is not initialized, it takes up some time for postgres to start up, set up data directories etc. However the server app connects to database right away so it can access it which throws this error:

```
api    | node:internal/process/promises:279
api    |             triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
api    |             ^
api    |
api    | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.24.0.2:5432
api    |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1157:16) {
api    |   errno: -111,
api    |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
api    |   syscall: 'connect',
api    |   address: '172.24.0.2',
api    |   port: 5432
api    | }
```

This can be fixed by restarting `api` service bit later. I would like to know what is the recommended solution. I expected that when postgres is warming up that any requests to the server process will be waiting to be processed but that's obviously not the case.

Should I use `is-port-reachable` dependency? I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66114637/3056783) answer to similar question could be a solution but I'm not sure if that is the correct approach. What if the `api` service wants to shutdown or there are already requests hitting the endpoints which need to access the database?

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/):

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  proxy:
    build: ./proxy
    networks:
      - frontend
  app:
    build: ./app
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
  db:
    image: postgres
    networks:
      - backend

networks:
  frontend:
    # Use a custom driver
    driver: custom-driver-1
  backend:
    # Use a custom driver which takes special options
    driver: custom-driver-2
```

As you can see, you can assign networks for your containers. I used it in a similar docker-compose with proxy, app and db (also postgres).

Note that you don't have t actually mention the drivers, but to assign a network to your containers:

```
networks:
      frontend:
      backend:
```

Comment: So how does splitting the network help my case? Will that mean the API service will wait for DB to respond to network requests?

Comment: Yes. The API will wait for the DB and now you ensure that they would be in the same network.