# docker-compose: How to check postgresql is up

Tags: docker

I have a docker compose file as below. One of the service starts a postgresql server.

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  postgresql:
    image: "postgres:13-alpine"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./DO_NOT_DELETE_postgres_data
        target: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: test
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: abc123
      PGDATA: "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata"
    networks:
      - postgresql_network

   otherservice:
      .... (there are few other services also here)

networks:
  postgresql_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Now I try to start the docker compose

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Now after this I have do some things with the postgresql database from another service `otherservice`

eg:

```
docker-compose exec otherservice psql -h postgresql -U postgres -p abc123
```

How to check the postgresql service is up

Answer (score 1):

> How to check the postgresql service is up

just to check the status you can just simply do `docker-compose ps` and look at the status.

To see if the service is just just up but is also ready (aka healthy), you can utilize [health checks](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#healthcheck). Use [pg_isready](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/app-pg-isready.html) for that.

If you want to start that `other` service only after the postgres service is up, go with [depends_on](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#depends_on) directive.

Comment: is it pg_ready ? regarding pg_ready - https://stackoverflow.com/a/67363257/2897115. Its not reliable