# How to make Postgres connect to Nodejs using docker-compose file? Getting Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.24.0.3:5432

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am taking a docker course by Stephen Grider where he sets up a Fibonacci series app that stores the index in PostgreSQL database. While calculating the value using redis. The entire thing is connected using docker-compose file. But due to some unknown issues, the API couldn't connect to the PostgreSQL and it shows the error. Any possible solution for this?

[image]

Comment: That is either a network problem, or `listen_addresses` is set incorrectly, or PostgreSQL is not running.

Comment: Hey. I have answered the question. Kindly go through it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker wait for postgresql to be running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35069027/docker-wait-for-postgresql-to-be-running)

Comment: Your answer shows that PostgreSQL was not started.

Comment: Yes. It took some time to start after downloading. But the next time it started directly.

Comment: @Phil
Tried the steps with depends_on, command bash but it didn't work. Finally tried the answered method and it worked.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To my understanding, it occurs due to the time taken for resources to download and start up. On checking the logs, I found out that my server tried making connection even before `postgres` database has started. And **I am guessing this might have**  resulted in an error. So to tackle this, I ran the command twice.
The first `docker-compose up --build` to download the resources. The second time to connect them. As this time, the postgres is already downloaded, I didn't face the error.

If anyone has any solution as how to make api start only after postgres has downloaded and started, do answer.