# Postgres-Sequalize-Docker problems in connection

Tags: postgresql, docker, express, docker-compose, sequelize.js

**TLDR:**
Server can connect when run seperatly and db-port 5432 is exposed. Server cannot connect when started in the same docker-compose.yml and is in the same network.
Server seems to connect on startup but then sends ECONNREFUSED error.

---

### Idea

docker-compose.yml with **2 services**:

- database: postgres:alpine
- express-server:   node:alpine

### Trys

I tried running the postgres container by itself with port 5432 exposed, then connected to it through
**NodeJs - Express - Sequalize**

When run as described, everything works.

Then started with docker-compose up, the server crashes because of an ECONNREFUSED. Here is the given Error:

```
original: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 217.196.149.50:5432
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1555:16) {
    errno: -111,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '217.196.149.50',
    port: 5432
  }
}
```

###### THE DOCKER-COMPOSE.YML

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      # POSTGRES_PORT: ${POSTGRES_PORT}
      # POSTGREST_HOST: ${POSTGRES_HOST}
    # ports:
    #   - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - default
  server:
    container_name: server
    depends_on:
     - postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
      POSTGRES_PORT: ${POSTGRES_PORT}
      POSTGREST_HOST: ${POSTGRES_HOST}
    build: ./server
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./server/app.js:/usr/app/app.js
    networks:
      - default
networks:
  default:
    name: pg-net
```

###### Server.JS

```
const express = require('express');
const { Sequelize, DataTypes, DATE } = require('sequelize');

/*
################
* SET-UP Section
################
*/

//* Server
const xp = express();
const port = 3000;
// const host = 'localhost';

//* Postgres
const postgresPassword = '';
const postgresUser = '';
const postgresDB = '';
const postgresPort = '';
const postgresHost = '';

// Option: Passing parameters separately (other dialects)
// const sq = new Sequelize(postgresDB, postgresUser, postgresPassword, {
//   host: postgresHost,
//   dialect: 'postgres' /* one of 'mysql' | 'postgres' | 'sqlite' | 'mariadb' | 'mssql' | 'db2' | 'snowflake' | 'oracle' */
// });
const sq = new Sequelize(`postgres://${postgresUser}:${postgresPassword}@${postgresHost}:${postgresPort}/${postgresDB}`);
//check if connection is established
sq.authenticate()
    .then(console.log('Connection to DB has been established successfully.'))
    .catch(error => console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error));
// define a Model
const User = sq.define('User', {
    // Model attributes are defined here
    ip: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    date: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE
        // allowNull defaults to true
    },
    data: {
        type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING)
    }
}, {
    // Other model options go here
    freezeTableName: true
});
console.log(User === sq.models.User); // true
// create Table in DB
User.sync();

/* 
################
* Server Routes and Functions
################
*/
xp.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send('Hello World!');
});

//* Postgres
xp.get('/setpostgres', (req, res) => {
    console.log("########       /setpostgres");
    const date = new Date();
    const data = User.create({ ip: req.ip, date: date })
        .then(data => {
            res.status(200).send(data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send(err);
        });
});

xp.get('/getpostgres', (req, res) => {
    console.log("########      /getpostgres");
    const data = User.findAll()
        .then(data => {
            res.status(200).send(data);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send(err);
        });
});
/*
################
* Server Start
################
*/

xp.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port: ${port}`);
}
);
```

---

### HELP

So what could I do so that sequalize is able to connect to the postgres-container?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker wait for postgresql to be running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35069027/docker-wait-for-postgresql-to-be-running)

Comment: You don't seem to have set any of the connection parameters in your application (they are all empty strings); what are you trying to actually connect to?  What is the IP address in the error message and how does the application find it?

Answer (score 0):

### Solved

The container with the server was not linked on the postgres-net. after connecting, everything worked out allright! thank you!

Comment: In the question, both containers are set to `networks: [default]` which is correct.  This is also Compose's default setting, and it would be safe to delete these `networks:` blocks.  What concrete change are you proposing?

Comment: I added an external network named 'master' and then added each container to that network whilst giving them an alias. Now they start-up fine in the network and are all listed.

Even though originally i just added/manipulated info of the default network, the server ended up not being connected to the manipulated default network. Therefor the 2nd strategy with an external network.